# Singularity and evaporation of black hole

Tags: black-holes, quantum-gravity, hawking-radiation, singularities

A question I have found that, [in a question](http://www.physics4all.com/questions/after-a-black-hole-evaporates-what-happens-to-the-singularity/) it is saying that what will be happened to the singularity when black hole evaporates. But recently I have checked that Stephen Hawking denied the singularity. Is there anythng wrong in my understanding?

Comment: What would cause a black hole to evaporate?

Comment: Hawking radiation causes a black hole to evaporate.  The idea is that when "virtual" electron-positron pairs are created near the event horizon however before they can annihilate one of the virtual particles gets caught within the event horizon while the other escapes rendering it a "real" particle. Since these particles initially come from "nothing" then to make up for this difference the black hole loses mass-energy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Singularities have not been rigorously proven to even exist.  However many physicist believe that they may exist.  Due to cosmic censorship, we can never know weather it did or didn't exist after the black hole evaporated with our current theories.  I do not believe there is anything wrong with your understanding since the nature of singularities is not well understood to begin with.  If they do exist then there must be a mechanism for dissembling it when total evaporation manifests.  I think your question is a good question but it is an artifact of the current lack of understanding of singularities.  Your question is a reasonable one.